# how to retrieve multiple images from database laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to retrieve multiple images of single user..?
anybody pls help me.

Controller:

```
public function fetch(){

    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $ads = Ads::where('user_id', $id)->with('images')->get();

    return view('home', ['ads'=> $ads]);
}
```

Blade View:

```
@foreach ($ads as $ad)

                <div class="card" onclick="" style="width: 19rem; float:left; margin-left: 10px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:50px; ">
                    <div class="card-header"> {{ $ad->product_name }} </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                                <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height: 200px;">

                                        <!-- Indicators -->
                                        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                                          <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                          <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                          <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <!-- The slideshow -->
                                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                                          <div class="carousel-item active">


                                                @foreach ($ads->images as $item)



                                            <img src="{{asset('storage/app/images/'.$item->filename)}}" alt="Los Angeles">

                                            @endforeach


                      @endforeach
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Your blade is missing some closing tags

Comment: Just tell me how to retrieve multiple images in blade? Code pls?

Answer (score 0):

`images` function in your Model should use `hasMany` rather `belongsTo`

Comment: Thank you but i want blade code? How can i retrieve images in blade?